# Upside down browser in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing a WPF application using Csharp. Its a touch application that has four browser windows displayed. Two upside down. The screen will be built into a table and lie flat. Four people will use the table - two on one side and two on the other. Thus the need for the upside down (or 180 degree rotation) browsers. I have tried using SilverLight and its Browser Brush. This works to display the browser content upside down BUT to interact with the browser you have to make the browser control active (instead of the Brush) and this turns the content back the right way up. I guess what I need is a Browser control that can be rotated in the normal way and work rotated. IE in Dot Net wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sascha Barber and Chris Cavanagh have blog posts about an alternative WebBrowser Control based on Chromium that behaves like a real WPF control. Check out http://sachabarber.net/?p=597 and http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/

Comment: Hi Jens, I have a look and let you know.

Comment: Hi Jens, It looks like AwesomiumSharp will work but I'm having a few problems getting it working. Just part of the learning curve I think. Thanks for you post.

Answer (score 1):

If it is WPF application you can use a simple RotateTransform to rotate controls any degree you want. So upside down should be no problem.

[Sample/Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid this won't affect the web content showing in the browser control.

Comment: @Joey: so following your logic an Image Control should not rotate an Image which it is containing...

Comment: Hi Holli, Im afraid its not that simple. You cant rotate a Browser control. Well you can but the content is still up the right way.

Comment: This has to do with the fact that it's an COM control. This creates interop issues, so you don't have scaling, rotating, etc.