# WPF WebBrowser C# Windows won't rotate the rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

This was supposed to be a simple task. I am trying to create a WPF application that would rotate the WebBrowser and it's web rendering upon clicking the button. So Ideally, this is what I want:

Original Browser:
[image]

Rotated Browser:
[image]

To achieve the task; following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestClawCam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int height = 480;
        int width = 640;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            clawCam1.Source= new Uri("http://google.com");
            clawCam1.Width = width;
            clawCam1.Height = height;


        }

        private void rotateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RotateTransform myTransform = new RotateTransform();
            myTransform.Angle = 90;
            clawCam1.RenderTransform = myTransform;

        }
    }
}
```

Upon running the code only the dimensions are changing but not the actual rendering. This is the output I am getting:

Original Browser:
[image]

Rotated Browser:
[image]

As you can see the dimensions changed but not the actual webpage. Following are the links I have already checked:

[Rotating webbrowser from current orientation is stretching(zooming) the webbrowser contents Windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378319/rotating-webbrowser-from-current-orientation-is-stretchingzooming-the-webbrows)

[Upside down browser in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274861/upside-down-browser-in-wpf-application)

[Rotate Windows form upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795957/rotate-windows-form-upside-down)

Also, if it is a label/image/canvas it would rotate the dimensions and appears to rotate the whole object. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. System configuration:

Windows 7

Visual Studio 2012

.Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're trying do do it just won't work. `RenderTransform` is a WPF concept, but the `WebBrowser` control doesn't use the WPF rendering pipeline. Under the hood, it's just an Internet Explorer window. Just like `WindowsFormsHost`, it overlays a *different* window object on top of the WPF display, and no WPF property can affect its contents in any way.

If you want to rotate the web content, you'll have to convince IE to do that. It won't be perfect, but you should be able to get pretty close depending on the content you want to display. The simplest solution I could think of is to use CSS transforms, so we'll inject a stylesheet to the page.

First, you'll have to add a reference to MSHTML, IE's rendering engine. It's a COM reference:

[image: Reference MSHTML]

Then, you'll have to handle the `Navigated` event:

```
clawCam1.Navigated += OnNavigated;
```

And you do the dirty work inside the event handler:

```
private void OnNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = clawCam1.Document as HTMLDocument;
    if (doc == null)
        return;

    var css = doc.createStyleSheet(string.Empty, 0);
    css.cssText = "body { transform: rotate(90deg); }";
}
```

Here's the result I get:

[image: Result]

Comment: OnNavigated does not exist in the current context..please help me. Which reference i have to add for clear this error. @PseudoAj

Comment: @arund `OnNavigated` is the function I wrote in the answer, just add it to your class.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski please share Xaml code i need to check how you use navigate because i cant use in xaml.

Comment: @arund I don't have it anymore, but it was trivial, just put `<WebBroswer x:Name="clawCam1" />` in the window and that's it. As you've now asked *two* trivial questions, something tells me you need to learn C# and WPF first, before attempting to mess around with hacks such as the one in the answer.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for your advise. i know what i need to do. Now you can go and do your work.

Comment: clawCam1.Document as HTMLDocument is not working it can not cast webbrowser.document to htmldocument how do you solve this @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: @Borshonsaydurrahman I don't know, it works for me. Ask a new question, add a link to this post, and provide as much details as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating web browser looks more problematic than one can think, so in fact neither LayoutTransform nore RenderTransform do work, if you need to rotate web browser you need to use [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does the same thing. Did you try the code? If yes, is it working? If yes, what's system config.

Comment: Hey @Hasson appreciate your effort, I am aware of chromium plugins to achieve it but I am looking for a native solution. I need this in a bigger project that is deployed across several systems.

Comment: @pseudoAJ if you make even remotely serious project using web browser in WPF - don't use built-in WebBrowser - it's very, very bad in _many_ aspects. Just use CefSharp (chromium) - several MB of additional files to copy but you won't waste your time trying to solve one issue after another with wpf WebBrowser like you do now.

Comment: I agree @Evk but this is a larger project that has been developed over the years(and wpf wasn't my choice).